# How to separate number of users in between constant timer in JMeter

Tags: timer, jmeter, constants

I want to hit Google website in following scenario:
1. 10 users hitting www.google.com
2. After 1 Minute, another 20 people hitting the same site

I am using Constant timer but would like to know how can I distribute number of users in between the timer because only in Thread Group we can mention the number of Users.

Below is the screenshot of my testplan:
https://www.cubbyusercontent.com/pli/test_plan.png/_c2b63f5c1e8940e9a72b66056181bfd4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it through ultimate or stepping threadgroup plugin.
like,

[image]

for this plugins visit [stepping threadgroup](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/)